# How do I write a function that returns a list of dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python

> Write a function that returns a list of dictionaries, where each
>   dictionary has the three keys `Product`, `Brand`, and `Cost`. The
>   function asks the user to input values for the keys until the user
>   inputs quit. For instance, if the user enters the following values
>
> ```
>  Enter Product: Milk 
>  Enter Brand: Anchor  
>  Enter Cost: 4.90 
>
>  Enter Product: Bread  
>  Enter Brand: Vogel  
>  Enter Cost: 3.80 
>
>  Enter Product: quit
> ```

Having asked the same question, I come up with this:

I wonder if this is the right step.

```
def run():
    i = True
    dic_keys = ['Milk', 'Brand', 'Cost']
    products = []
    product = {}

    while i:
        for key in dic_keys:
            name_dict = input("Enter Product: ")
        if i != "quit":
```

Comment: Why is 'Milk' hardcoded? You probably mean 'Product', there.

Comment: In general, your code goes in the right direction, but you need to make some things clearer in your mind. Why would `i` ever equal "quit"? How are the values going into the `product` dict, and how does the dict go into the `products` list? How will several `product` dicts be created when the user enters several products?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that's the right direction, but as the comments pointed out, you have to get a bit more clear on how your code should work.
 A possible way you could go would be:

```
def run():
    dic_keys = ['Product', 'Brand', 'Cost']
    products = []

    while True:
        # get an emtpy product dict for every new product
        product = {}

        # get user input for every key (product, brand, cost)
        for key in dic_keys:
            # get input
            val = input(f"Enter {key}: ")

            # if the input is "stop": return results ("quit" is already a python keyword)
            if val == "stop":
                return products

            # add user input to corresponding key (eg. val: Bread, key: Product)
            product[key] = val

        # after we went through all the keys the product dict is finished, so it gets appended to teh products list
        products.append(product)


myProducts = run()
print(myProducts)
```

Comment: The OP wants the `quit` instead of `stop`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is OK and maintainable if you would like to add another keys, but it needs some fixes.

Try this. It just include one loop only.

```
list_= []                                      
d = {}                                         

i = input("Enter Product: ")              

while(i != "quit"):                            
    d["product"] = i                           
    d["Brand"] = input("Enter Brand: ")   
    d["Cost"] = int(input("Enter Cost: "))

    list_.append(d)                            
    i = input("Enter Product: ")          

print(list_)
```

Answer (score 0):

I created the exact function you were looking for. Let me share my code with you first, then I will explain it.

```python
# BLL
def get(product,brand,cost):                            ..8
    d1 = {"Product":product,"Brand":brand,"Cost":cost}  ..9
    List.append(d1)                                     ..10
    print(d1)                                           ..11
    print(List)                                         ..12


# PL
List = []                                                        ..1
while(1):                                                        ..2
    product=input("Enter the Product").strip().lower().title()   ..3
    if(product=="Quit"):                                         ..4
        break
    brand = input("Enter the Brand").strip().lower().title()     ..5
    cost = int(input("Enter the cost"))                          ..6
    get(product,brand,cost)                                      ..7
```

Let's start from the code block written under `# PL` (Presentation layer). 
In the first line, I created an empty list which will be storing all the dictionaries as a list.
In the 2nd line, I used `while(1)` so that the code would run again and again and would require input from the user.
In the 3rd, 5th and 6th lines, I just ask the user to give the required inputs. Here, I have used `strip().lower().title()` to store the input in a fixed font, irrespective how the user provides it.
In the 4th line, I used an `if` statement so that as soon as the user gives `"Quit"` as input, the program would terminate.
In the 7th line, I finally call the function.

Now let's see the code written in `# BLL` layer - how the function is going to work when it's called.
In the 8th line, I just called the function `get` and passed the three keys(`Product`, `Brand`, `Cost`).
In the 9th line, I stored the inputs given by the user in the dictionary.
In the 10th line, I added the whole dictionary into the list using `append` - remember, I created an empty list in line 1.
In the 11th and 12th line, I just return the dictionary and the list to the user.

[image: Output Window]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to sanitize the input;

```
dic_keys = ['Product', 'Brand', 'Cost']

dic = dict(zip(dic_keys, [input(f'Enter {key}') for key in dic_keys]))
```

Output;

```
Enter Product     Milk
Enter Brand       CowTeat
Enter Cost        6
{'Product': 'Milk', 'Brand': 'CowTeat', 'Cost': '6'}
```

So if you want a list of dictionaries;

```
account = []
while True:
    try:
        account.append(dict(zip(dic_keys, [input(f'Enter {key}') for key in dic_keys])))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

Press Ctrl-C when finished with the input.